# How to create a csv from an uneven/inconsistent dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which are uneven/inconsistent in format, by which I mean that the keys are not consistent throughout the dictionaries. I want to create a csv file which contains all the data in the dictionaries, where a new column is created when a new key is encountered when iterating through the dictionaries.

For example:
input = [{"name": "John}, {"name": "Bob", "age":"55"}, {"age": "43"}, {"name": "Phil", "age": "60", "job": "Builder"}]

should become:

| name | age | job |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John |  |  |
| Bob | 55 |  |
|  | 43 |  |
| Phil | 60 | Builder |

My current attempt looks like this:

to extract all keys in the inconsistent dictionaries for us as fieldnames (column headers in csv):

```
def extract_fields(raw_data):
    fields = []
    for i in raw_data:
        for j in i.keys():
            if j not in fields:
                fields.append(j)
    return fields
```

To write a csv using extracted fieldnames:

```
def export_csv(input, fields):
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, fields)
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerows(input)
```

I can't figure out a way to make sure that the key-values map correctly once the 'writerows' function is used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has solved my issue:

```
def export_csv(input, fields):
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fields, delimiter=',')
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(input)
```

I included the 'fieldnames=' and 'delimiter=' kwargs.

Comment: Your answer should include an additional sentence or two explaining what you changed/added to get your solution working.